# Node Sequelize cannot connect to MySQL SSL

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect my node app to my remote MySQL server and I am getting the following error:

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'remoteUser'@'mysqlIpAddress' (using password: YES)

However, I can connect to the mysql server just fine by using the following command.

mysql -u remoteUser -h 138.68.15.94

Here is my connection string

```js
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.mysql.database, config.mysql.user, config.mysql.password, {
    host: config.mysql.host,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    ssl: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: true
    },
    define: {
      timestamps: false
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    },
  })
```

Any help would be great! I've been fighting this the past two days.

Comment: Everything looks good. Re-check your db credentials, is password required?

Comment: Yes, password is required. I've noticed that sequelize is appending the IP Address along with the login. When I do that via mysql command, I receive the same error. Is there a way to tell sequelize to not append the IP Address to the user name?

Comment: I don't think that matters. Try logging in with the same credentials from another SQL client

Comment: I can connect fine if SSL is turned off. I'll have to try testing out your method.